# Why is UIDatePicker in countdown mode 1 hour behind?

Tags: xcode, uidatepicker

If I set the UIDatePicker's date in countdown mode to "1970-01-01 00:05:00 +0000" it shows [ 1hour | 5min ] - why is that?

Set the date (in a different class):

```
_countdownTime=[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:5*60];
```

Create picker and assign date:

```
//setup a date picker as countdown picker
    UIDatePicker *countdownPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [countdownPicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [countdownPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];
    [countdownPicker setMinuteInterval:5];
    [countdownPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateCountdownTimeText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [countdownPicker setDate:[myAction getCountdownTime]];
```

Comment: Have you considered timezones/locales? Also 5*60 means what? Checkout the WWWDC 2012 session on calendrical calculations. That session basically says about the that calculation: 'You're doing it wrong, use system supplied ways of handling dates and times". In other words: use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents instead of n*minutes or x*hours or similar computations. Also, try and prevent setting something to midnight, as midnight can confuse systems (does midnight belong to end of the evening of day1, or to the start of the night of day2?).

Comment: It looks like you're not setting the time zone, so it's using the system's current time zone - which time zone are you in?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am in GMT+1 time zone. I added the line `[countdownPicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];` to the picker, but still the same issue.

Comment: @Joride Thanks for your comments, what's your suggestion to use instead of 5*60? I thought NSTimeInterval is of type float anyway.

Comment: Create an NSCalendar. Get from the calendar an NSDateComponents object for the current date/time. Add 5 to the hours of the components obkect. Ask the calendar for an NSDate from those adjusted components. This will guarantee that you get what you want, it tales into account all timezone and geopolitical weirdnesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is at least somewhat a guess... I'm not an iOS expert at all.)

Well it sounds like the problem is precisely because you're using a time zone which is GMT+1 - or was in January 1970, anyway.

Basically I think the `UIDatePicker` is showing you the local time of the given `NSDate`, with the relevant time zone applied. `initWithTimeIntervalSince1970` initializes a date with the given number of seconds since the Unix epoch, which is midnight *UTC*.

I suggest you set the time zone to UTC:

```
[countdownPicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Then hopefully it'll show what you expected...